# How to create an animation in a splash screen?

Tags: android, android-animation

When we open a app we get different type of animated object or people moving around in the splash screen of an app for example like a person running while the app is loaded or the name of the app falls and a guy sits on it clicking photos.

How can we create one and what type of software do we use?

Can you suggest me some tutorials to follow?

Comment: use gif file to achieve this

Comment: Use video in the Splash Screen

Comment: I am creating a video. Does it need to have specific dimensions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android image animation for splash screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536452/android-image-animation-for-splash-screen)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. use gif

OR

2. use Animation :

   Ex) Awesome-looking customizable splash screen : [AwesomeSplash](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2605)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use your own created gif images to show on the `imageview` at splash screen through Glide image loading and caching library.

Like :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);

Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.gif_image).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Answer (score 5):

**paste this xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >

    <scale
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

and on the splash screen

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(contex, R.anim.blink);
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setDuration(700);
```

and use this Animation like

```
final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnrecievecall);
        splash.startAnimation(animation)
```

Answer (score 3):

1.. use gif file
or 
2.. First using set animation effect, and after direct using this image splace screen.

Comment: which animation software can i use to create one?

Comment: @kautilyahari search google many types of link set animation effect set using image in android